# add sharing/read-write - Ubuntu 17.0.4

Tags: file-sharing

I'm new to Ubuntu, so please go easy on me. I'm 73 and fragile. Ha.

I use Quicken on a drive running Win10 Pro and I just set up another drive with Ubuntu 17.

I have read quite a lot on how to share a file and quite frankly am pretty dazzled at this point. When I began reading about sharing, authors stated how easy it is to do this. Several days later, I'm not so sure.

I created a folder on the Ubuntu Desktop and called it Quicken. Then I right-clicked and went to Share. I was asked for Permissions and went through that process and then back to Share. When I click on Share, nothing seems to happen except the button grays-out. I don't know if it worked or didn't.

Then I went to Windows and set up a Desktop folder pointing to the Linux folder. Fine. I can see the Linux (Quicken) folder inside Windows and can access it by double-clicking it. However, (in Windows) I try to backup the file from Quicken to that Linux folder and get a message that the drive/file is read-only.

Amongst other things, I've read about changing "ro" to "rw" such as in a Linux line that contains "ro quiet splash $ vt_handoff" to: "rw init=/bin/bash". I'm really confused to say the least. Is there really a simple method to share this file between Windows and Linux? I'd love to see it. Much thanks. Chuck in Boston.

Comment: Are you running one of the operating systems as a virtual machine, or do you shutdown windows completely when you want to run Ubuntu?  The process that you described for file sharing is something that would be done between two *running* operating systems (and is not entirely trivial!)

Answer (score 0):

Linux folder? windows can't access a ext4 file system. the simplest way to share between linux and windows is to make a small partition formatted to ntfs.

both systems will be able to read and write to this partition.

Comment: I believe that the OP is attempting to use SMB to access storage on the linux system.

Comment: @charles -- yes which is why windows can't write to it.  the folder is on a ext4 drive. it may work if the file is on the windows partition and shares with linux, since linux can read and write ntfs. He also asked for the easiest way to share files between the two OS's.

Comment: Eh - I have no problems sharing a folder on my ext4 drives to Windows (running in qemu) using SAMBA - there was some setup that needed to be done in the beginning, but otherwise it's transparent.

Comment: @charles, qemu is a VM, thus the base system is still linux, with a windows emulation. The OP has a windows install and a linux install, if I read correctly, thus two different operating systems. I may be wrong about getting windows to write to a shared folder on an ext partition, but making a ntfs partition for sharing is still the easiest way.

Comment: If they are both running, it may be, although SMB was not terribly difficult.  I think the OP is dual booting, and either using a separate ntfs partition or mounting the Win10 disk will have to be his solution.

Comment: @charles-- they do not both have to be running to use the same partition. and actually with a dual boot it is impossible for both to be running.